# How to properly retain NSArray or basic use

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an nsarray that when I NSLog it from one of my methods I can see its contents, but when I try to look inside it from elsewhere it seems to be empty. I am aware that my memory management needs some work, could anyone help explain whats happening here?

**NEW CODE**

**WorkOutList.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface WorkOutList : UIViewController {

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *customWorkouts;
    NSArray *passedWorkout;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *customWorkouts;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *passedWorkout;

-(IBAction)customWorkouts:(id)sender;

-(void)passWorkoutBack:(NSArray *)workout;


@end
```

**WorkOutList.m**

```
@implementation WorkOutList

@synthesize managedObjectContext, customWorkouts, passedWorkout;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self setupContext];
    NSLog(@"View Did Load");
    customWorkouts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    passedWorkout = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self fetchWorkoutList];
    NSLog(@"View will Appear");
    NSLog(@"Array from View Will Appear : %@", passedWorkout);

}

-(IBAction)customWorkouts:(id)sender{
    CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    SelectedWorkout *selectedWorkout = [[SelectedWorkout alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [selectedWorkout recieveNeededData:customWorkouts];

    [appDelegate.practiceNavController pushViewController:selectedWorkout animated:YES];
    [selectedWorkout release];
}

-(void)passWorkoutBack:(NSArray *)workout{
    passedWorkout = workout;
    [passedWorkout retain];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**SelectedWorkout.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SelectedWorkout : UITableViewController {


    NSMutableArray *workoutListForTable;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *workoutListForTable;

-(void)recieveNeededData:(NSMutableArray *)workoutList;

@end
```

**SelectedWorkout.m**(aside from all the stuff to set up the tableView)

```
    @implementation SelectedWorkout

    @synthesize workoutListForTable;

    -(void)recieveNeededData:(NSMutableArray *)workoutList{

        if (workoutListForTable != workoutList) {
            workoutListForTable = workoutList;  
        }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        WorkOutList *workoutListView = [[WorkOutList alloc]init];

        [workoutListView passWorkoutBack:[workoutListForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [appDelegate.practiceNavController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    - (void)dealloc {

        [workoutListForTable release];
        [super dealloc];
    }


    NSLog(@"other table : %@", workoutListForTable);
    [workoutListForTable retain];
}
```

Comment: where are you calling passWorkoutBack this function in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear?

Comment: i am calling it from a separate class

Comment: but did you check, viewDidLoad is called before or after passWorkoutBack function is called?

Comment: Its called after, "And I checked in the NSLog and Passed Array 1 is logged as being first..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think I understand about the flow of your app:

1. passWorkoutBack gives your view controller an NSArray, which it places in 'passedWorkout'.
2. viewDidLoad is called and your 'passedWorkout' is reinitialised as an empty array.
3. viewWillAppear is called and you realise your array is empty.

To be honest, I think this comes from a lack of understanding of designing robust code (don't worry, it's the hardest thing to learn in programming). Here are a few tips that I think would make this app flow smoother:

1. Create a new init method for your viewController class and, in it, include an argument to give pass this workout array.
2. If you get an array from somewhere, all you need to do is retain it (either by using a property as Inspire48 said, or by calling retain on the object as you've already done), you don't even need to allocate or initialise the array before you get it from wherever you get it.
3. Understand the viewController lifecycle. Do you know the difference between viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear? If you don't, learn, because they are both good tools when utilised properly.

Anywho, I hope this helped and that I wasn't too 'preachy'. I'm assuming a lot about your app and you, so correct me on anything I'm wrong about. Cheers.

Comment: But the thing is that viewDidLoad is called the first time that I come to this specific view controller,which is fine. However from here I travel to a TableViewController and select the array that I want. Before pop'ing back to the original view controller I started at I call `-(void)passWorkoutBack:(NSArray *)workout` which defines what should be inside `passedWorkout` but when I pop back into the original view controller it does not seem that viewDidLoad is called again, because none of my `NSLogs` inside of it are called. Confusing me why my array would be cleared out. Thoughts?

Comment: That has to do with the viewController life cycle I was talking about. viewDidLoad is only called after the viewController is initialised, same as init. Whereas, viewWillAppear is called every time its view is about to appear. viewDidLoad is really for setting things up after the view is created from a nib, because your IBOutlets won't have been created when your init method is called.

Comment: Right, so then if I init my passedWorkout in the viewDidLoad how is it being initialized as a new array when I return to the view controller?

Comment: The second array is being initialised by whatever's calling 'passWorkoutBack:'. When you set the 'passedWorkout' with the array you get from that, you're overwriting the old one (the empty one) as though it was never there (so to speak).

Comment: Sorry man, I just am not getting this, I think its just something really simple that Im missing. I tried removing the property and the init from it, still no luck. I'm going to paste as much code as possible in the top to see if it makes since.

Answer (score 3):

Your memory management is fine albeit a bit awkward—you could just declare a retained property and avoid that `retain` at the bottom. Your issue though comes from the fact that 'viewWillAppear:' is being called before 'passWorkoutBack:', so it's blank at 2 because 2 is being called before 1. If you're expecting something at 2, then your 'fetchWorkoutList' method isn't working properly.

Comment: but thats the thing, 2 is not being called before 1, because i am calling 1 from a different class before i tell it to popViewController  In the NSLog 1 comes before 2, and 1 has data and 2 does not.

Comment: Would this be what you mean by a retained property?     @property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *passedWorkout;

Comment: Yep. Then in the latter method you could just write `self.passedWorkout = workout;` and skin the `retain` underneath

Comment: To your first comment—What I think you're doing is passing in `workout` to the latter method before the view controller is loaded. Basically, passWorkoutBack (poorly named method, BTW—where is "back"?) is being called before `viewDidLoad`. And there lies your issue.

Comment: Maybe poorly named, but it goes ViewController(where all of these methods are) >> Table View  and then when the user selects one of the items it passes back the array attached to the item to ViewController. And if i put an NSLog in the viewDidLoad it doesnt get called thats why I'm using the viewWillAppear to check it.

Comment: also could you tell me what you mean by skin the retain?

Comment: Oops—I meant skip the retain. Anyway, now I'm really confused about the order of your method calls. So `UITableViewDelegate` has a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, which should mostly replace passWorkoutBack. passWorkoutBack is basically a glorified setter; you should just get the workout from your data source and set it to `passedWorkout`. But if the table view is already on screen, why are you concerned about `viewDidAppear`? When you push the VC on screen, it will call `viewDidLoad`, then `viewWillAppear`. The action method won't get called until much later.

Comment: ok so i made some slight changes, but still no luck, in the `tableView:didselectRowAtIndexPath:` method i added  `WorkOutList *workoutListView = [[WorkOutList alloc]init];

 [workoutListView setPassedWorkout:[workoutListForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: But it still doesn't seem to save the data when I try to retrieve it.

Comment: Why not just `self.passedWorkout = [workoutListForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`?

Comment: But passedWorkout is in a different class than the tableView.

Comment: @Inspire48 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1197/discussion-between-james-dunay-and-inspire48)

Comment: tried chat, no luck, also no idea why its not being saved, i am doing the exact same thing else where the only difference between the two is i use a NSMutableArray instead of NSArray.

Answer (score 2):

Your setter method should release the previous value and retain the new one, e.g.

```
– (void)passWorkoutBack:(NSArray *)workout {

    if (passedWorkout != workout) {

        [passedWorkout release];

        passedWorkout = [workout retain]; 

    }

}
```

Here, the `if` statement ensures that you don't accidentally release `workout` before it is retained.

Finally, since you call `alloc` in `viewDidLoad`, you should call `release` in viewDidUnload.

---

Since you are calling `alloc` and `init` in `viewDidLoad`, whatever value `passedWorkout` may have had is getting erased when this method is called. If you wish to retain its value even if the view is unloaded and reloaded, then you should allocate `passedWorkout` in the `init` method of the ViewController and, of course, release it in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Why are you using `isEqual:` rather than simple pointer comparison?

Comment: Oh. Dang, I thought you were about to teach me something clever.

Comment: Yep: Don't trust answers on SO to be perfect :-)

Comment: That still doesnt seem to be working, any ideas what i might be missing?

Comment: @James: If you put the `alloc` call in the `init` of your ViewController and subsequently call `release` in your `dealloc` method, then this will ensure the object is created. If you have a default value that you would like for `passedWorkout` to have, then you can also include that when you create and initialize it. Otherwise, it begins empty.

Comment: Thats the thing when i NSLog it from `passWorkoutBack:` method, it has a value. but when i look at it from `viewWillAppear:` its empty. what gives?

Comment: and in this case `passWorkoutBack:` is called before `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: Well i log it from `passWorkoutBack` just to test and it has a value, but when i log it from `viewWillAppear`, which comes after `passWorkoutBack`, it has no value.

Comment: passWorkoutBack is called before viewWillAppear

Comment: what is the init method of the viewController?

Comment: `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` -- this?

Comment: well tried that, no luck, i think it seems like `(void)passWorkoutBack:(NSArray *)workout` workout in here is being released or something, i have a extremely similar Array that is being init in the `viewDidLoad`. It has no problem remembering its data even when going back and forth between views.  Quite frustrating, but the only difference i can see is the how i `passedWorkout` gets is data